# Ember: Prevent transition based on response

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js, how do you conditionally prevent transition based on response?

For example, if the server returns a 403 (in the model hook), then display an alert and do not transition.

It's such a simple and common thing to do, yet I cannot find any documentation or guides to do so.

This is what I have so far

```
Ember.Route = Ember.Route.extend(InfinityRoute, {
  actions: {
    error: function(error){
      if (error.status === 403) {
        this.store.createRecord('notice', {
          message: "You are not authorized to view this content. Sorry man."
        });
      }
  }
```

The notice works, but I want to abort the transition. It'll probably have to be moved to another place, because by the time this error hook is run, the transition has already taken place

Comment: What response? 403 on page visit or on fetching the model? Mind adding some code and context to your question?

Comment: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/ and http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_when-promises-reject will be good starting points

Comment: @Knightsy please.. I have given up on Ember's guides long ago. They are pathetic and useless and I expect more from a framework like this

Comment: @Kitler A 403 on fetching the model. Check my edit

Comment: The error action has a [second param](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_error), you can abort the transition and handle the popup there.

Comment: "because by the time this error hook is run, the transition has already taken place"
You can catch the error on the model hook. As in `this.store.find('myModel').catch(function(e) { // your code });`

Comment: @Kitler.. When I read your comment about the second param, I thought this is my perfect solution. But I tried it and put `transition.abort()` into my error hook, but it didn't work. Which is weird.. Do you have any further ideas? As for your second comment(`this.store.find('myModel').catch(function(e) { // your code });`) .. I want this to be a generalized route that I can inherit from, so I want to try as far as possible not to have to put code in the model hook, because then I have to put it in all my model hooks

Comment: Create a route mixin that handles the error action, that way you can abort the transition from the route that throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, returning a rejected promise from the `model` hook (or `afterModel` or `beforeModel` will by itself cause the transition to fail (not proceed). So you don't need to do anything particular to abort the transition. If you want to put up an dialog box or something then:

```
model: function() {
    var model = this.store.find('my-model');
    model . catch(displayErrorMessage);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return model;
}
```

If for reason you prefer to explicitly abort the transition, do so using the second argument:

```
model: function(params, transition) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
    return this.store.find('my-model') .
        catch(() => { displayErrorMessage(); transition.abort() });
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Aborting transitions in `model` hooks is is described on the Guide page "PREVENTING AND RETRYING TRANSITIONS", at http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/:

> **ABORTING TRANSITIONS WITHIN `model`, `beforeModel`, `afterModel`**
>   The `model`, `beforeModel`, and `afterModel` hooks described in Asynchronous Routing each get called with a transition object. This makes it possible for destination routes to abort attempted transitions.

If you want to catch and do something with **all** failed ajax requests, then you can use the `ajaxComplete` call. This is not Ember per se, it's jQuery. Put up your dialog box or message there. The transition itself will be automatically aborted by the ajax error causing the promise from `this.store.find` to go into rejected state. Or abort it yourself.

Note that if you are using a loading substate, then it is impossible to abort the transition and stay where you are. It's too late.

> **EAGER VS. LAZY ASYNC TRANSITIONS**
>   ...once you provide a destination route loading substate, you are opting into an "eager" transition, which is to say that, unlike the "lazy" default, you will eagerly exit the source routes (and tear down their templates, etc) in order to transition into this substate.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on the base class of route, without having to put code in the model hook? I want the same behaviour for any 403, and I don't want to put this code into every single one of my model hooks

Comment: Actually any uncaught error (unhandled rejected promise) returning from the model hook will abort the transition. So that's not your problem. The problem is to put up the dialog box you want. In this case, I'd suggest something as simple as an `ajaxComplete` hook to handle that.

Comment: But it renders a blank page (in my case a loading spinner) .. But i want the app to just stay on the same page and just display a notice. Why would I want to switch to an empty page?

Comment: That's because you've eagerly advanced to a loading state. Once you've advanced to the loading state, it's too late to go back. You'll have to roll your own solution to the loading page problem.

Comment: Mmmm.. good thinking. Let me try removing the loading substate

Comment: You are exactly right @torazaburo, it was the loading substate that caused this